# How do I use nested | (or) operators in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
derp = "This Act may be cited as the `Clean Air Act Amendments of the 101st Congress'."
re.search("(can)|(may) be (cited)|(referred to) as the? `(.+)'",derp).group(5)
```

This re doesn't seem to work, and I think it has something to do with the grouping. Can someone help me group the clauses correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a choice of strings in a *regex*, use the form :

```
(?:can|may)
```

Note :

```
?:
```

stands for *non capturing group*, so no need to modify the group index

Comment: I would +1, but you need to change the group number since you've now reduced the numoer of capturing groups.

Comment: I had simplified my answer

Comment: most of the time you People are just way to quick for me :-)

Comment: unless you need the result of the match, i think it's best to use non-capturing groups... `(?:can|may)`

Answer (score 2):

```
  "(can|may) be (cited|referred to) as the? `(.+)'"
```

and don't Forget to modify your Group index...